# Unable to import Camera2 API

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

In following code Camera class is deprecated.and I'm unable to import camera2 class. MinSDKVersion is 21.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: @HemantParmar There is no option of camera2 in import. onlu hardware.camera and graphics.camera.

Comment: does your class extend Activity/Fragment?

Comment: @HemantParmar fragments